# Поиск по отсортированному массиву

Tags: массивы, поиск, алгоритм

Доброго времени суток!
какие есть алгоритмы поиска по отсортированному массиву(распределение данных - любое и нам не известное), быстрее чем за логарифм от размера массива?

Comment: Но есть и другие варианты поиска, кроме поиска по отсортированному массиву. Например хеш-таблицы... Классика жанра -- третий (если не путаю) том Кнута

Comment: бинарный поиск

Comment: @woland: бинарный поиск именно за логарифм.

Comment: если данные числовые (целые числа), а памяти хватает, то можно просто буленовый массив сделать. Тогда поиск будет почти O(1). Если данные абстрактные, то можно сделать хэш от данных и также хранить в буленовом массиве. Если хэш без коллизии, то поиск будет также почти O(1).

Во многих случаях бинарный поиск очень быстрый, главное сделать быстрым компаратор.

Comment: не понятно, про какой язык програмирования идет речь? или это логика в общем?

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае невозможно.

Смотрите, вот объяснение на пальцах (не претендует на строгость). Каждая элементарная проверка даёт вам один бит информации. За `k` проверок вы получаете `k` бит информации, на основе которых вы можете различить `2^k` различных случаев. Так что если длина массива `2^k`, за меньше чем `k` проверок вы не сможете добыть необходимую информацию.

Comment: Тут нет ограничения на то, что можно только сравнивать на < >. Так что было бы интересно услышать какие-то хитрые идеи

Comment: @Михаил М: В любом случае, одна элементарная проверка даёт O(1) бит информации. Поэтому мы в любом случае получим асимптотику не лучше, чем O(ln n).

Comment: @VladD, не готов спорить насчёт теоретического доказательства Вашего утверждения. Но в любом случае log 1 млрд. = 30, поэтому я не вижу смысла отвергать идеи, дающие ускорение в 5 или 30 раз. Потому что согласитесь, что получить вместо C * log 1 млрд. теоретически равнозначное C / 30 * log 1 млрд., на практике означает получить 1, т.е. О(1)

Comment: @Михаил М: с практической точки зрения вы правы. С теоретической для O-асимптотики первые несколько сотен значащих цифр не играют роли :-) Поскольку в своём вопросе автор неявно упоминает именно асимптотику, мой ответ выдержан в теоретическом ключе. Для ускорения, я бы, как и вы, посоветовал, например, одноразовую поразрядную индексацию, которая не улучшает асимптотику (в области действительно огромных чисел), но помогает в практических диапазонах.

Comment: Мда. "Разница между теорией и практикой гораздо больше на практике, чем в теории".


Ладно, чисто ради прикола: на теоретической машине с линейной адресацией размер адреса будет равен машинному слову. Так что одной удачной машинной инструкцией можно сдвинуться на N бит, где N - длина машинного слова. Например, когда будет в памяти помещаться 2^128 байт, регистры и операции уже тоже будут наверняка как минимум 128-битными. Таким образом может существовать алгоритм сложности 1 операция.

Comment: О, минус, круто. Уважаемый минусатор, объясните?

---
@Михаил М: и чем это опровергает мои выкладки? Замените для простоты 128 на `N`.

Comment: @Михаил М: Нет, не получили. Вы уверены в том, что понимаете смысл асимптотики и O-нотации? Потому что в условиях ограниченного размера памяти у вас не может размер контейнера стремиться к бесконечности. Никак.

Comment: @Михаил М: Вы, мне кажется, просто не поняли ответ. O(1) бит информации — это _не_ 1 бит информации. Откуда вы взяли, что ответ относится лишь к операциям сравнения? Вычисление хэш-функции, кстати, приносит тоже O(1) бит информации, подумайте об этом.

---
Когда говорится об асимптотике, имеется в виду сразу машина с бесконечной памятью. На машине с конечной памятью любая операция O(1), очевидно же.

Comment: @Михаил М: Теперь я уверен, что вы не знаете, что означает O-нотация. Сможете сформулировать _определение_ того, что алгоритм находит элемент в массиве длиной `N` за `O(log N)` (настоящее определение, а не в терминах «ну это когда»)?

Comment: Для любого N > некого N0 (т.е. при стремлении к бесконечности) найдётся константа C такая, что поиск в массиве длиной N будет требовать не более C * log N операций?



В одном стёбном фильме про полицейских (забыл название) были сценки вида "Я ходил на курсы дизайна чтобы ставить на место таких горе-художников" :))



Не, я понимаю на этом уровне всю эту кухню, фразу не нагуглил. Но смысла всё равно не вижу. Хотя готов признать, что на поле теории мой стёбный довод "на теоретической машине с линейной адресацией..." Вы опротестовали грамотно, хотя и ещё больше уйдя в теорию :)

Comment: @Михаил М: о, почти правильно. Я был не настолько уверен. На самом деле — найдётся такая константа `C`, одна для всех `N`, такая, что начиная с какого-то `N_0` количество операций меньше `C log N`. Отталкиваясь от этого определения, для компьютера с конечной памятью O-нотация не имеет смысла. Поэтому когда говорят о O-оценке, трюки, основанные на конечном размере памяти/шины данных сразу отметаются.

На конечной машине любой поиск O(1), согласно определению. Просто возьмите С = размеру памяти.

Answer (score 0):

Можно скомбинировать несколько методов. Допустим, если ключ - числа от 1 до 1000000 (все значения не обязаны присутствовать), то завести массив "указателей", допустим, по тысячам - p[i] = индекс первого элемента в исходном массиве, ключ которого >= i * 1000. Только вместо 1000 лучше выбрать степень двойки, так как на неё делить.

После нахождения подмножества тоже можно либо линейным поиском, либо бинарным. Вобщем, на упорядоченности можно хорошо играть